# The difference between setting the value and the text using JSE (Selenium c#)

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using **IjavaScriptExecutor** to set Atrribute **value**.
But sometimes it happens that my text box contains value I setted , but it is not displaying it as a text. So literally to some text boxes it is sending an input normally and to some of them not. It is just setting the value. But not displaying the text.
Why is this happening?

**CODE:**

```
 public static void SendKeysJavaScript(IWebElement element, string message)
    {
        //Instance of IJavaScriptExecutor class
        var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) Program.Driver;
        //Local variable holding formated string
        var stringFormat = string.Format("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','{0}')", message);
        //Send "message" to the "element"
        js.ExecuteScript(stringFormat, element);
        //confirm that input has been sent
        GetSentInput(element, message);
    }
```

Also in the meantime, I have noticed that the text boxes even when cleared are still keeping the value. Which might be one of the reasons why I can't send input to the same text box twice, what is the way of resetting the value ?

Comment: When automating scenarios, you want to perform actions as a user would as much as possible. In cases like these you should use .SendKeys() and not the JSE. Using the JSE can modify the element directly bypassing "normal" user behavior and can cause issues.

Comment: @JeffC Interesting, I've been told to use JSE because it's increasing performance dramatically, and it is always better way of sending an input to the browser.

Comment: I have never heard anything about JSE being faster. My guess is that it's either about the same or slightly slower. JSE is for when you need to execute JavaScript against the page. It's not intended to do "normal" user tasks. That's what WebDriver is for.

Comment: @Mystia using JS for your end to end testing is awful behaviour. Your tests should validate user journeys but that isn't the case here.

Comment: @Arran Thank you, no, you are right that is not the case here. I have started using selenium recently and I am steel exploring the capabilities of the Selenium, don't know much about it yet. But I am glad at least that I have asked this question otherwise I would be still believing that JS is a great choice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Text` property of C# returns the innertext which is *The expected return value is roughly what a text-only browser would display.*. See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#getelementtext)

On the other hand, `value` is the attribute here, at least the way your are using. So only way to manipulate that is to use JavaScript Executor.

Now, taking a deeper look into the problem and if I understand it correctly, the `clear()` method does not trigger the change of event the application expected and thus, you do not see any change. To trigger the change there are multiple options including the one I have taken from `Selenium` Java source code.

> /**
>      * If this element is a text entry element, this will clear the value. Has no effect on other
>      * elements. Text entry elements are INPUT and TEXTAREA elements.
>      *
>      * Note that the events fired by this event may not be as you'd expect.  In particular, we don't
>      * fire any keyboard or mouse events.  If you want to ensure keyboard events are fired, consider
>      * using something like {@link #sendKeys(CharSequence...)} with the backspace key.  To ensure
>      * you get a change event, consider following with a call to {@link #sendKeys(CharSequence...)}
>      * with the tab key.
>      */

`void clear();`